# Is it possible to use animate the top positioning of an element using percentages and a variable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, css-position

'thisAnchorMargin is an float. why doesn't this work? if i just put a numerical value in there and don't concatenate the % (e.g. top: 50%) it works. is this not a valid unit type to animate in jquery?

```
$('.markerContainer').stop().animate({
    top: thisAnchorMargin + '%'
    }, {
    duration:scrollSpeedGlobal,
    queue:false
    });
```

Comment: What's the behavior when it "doesn't work"? Are there any errors in the javascript error console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it with several different floats (concatenating the '%') and it works just fine, at least in Chrome/Mac. http://jsfiddle.net/9d6ck/

Comment: Methinks other evil things might be at play.

Comment: turns out that it was just the fact that the values i was getting were just soooo miniscule that there wasn't any visible animation going on... thanks for all the replies!